# Why does the Notes application treat notes different in different iCloud accounts?

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I have two separate iCloud accounts, with the Notes application (latest Mac OS) configured to use both iCloud accounts.

Notes stored in my primary iCould account work as expected. But notes in the second iCloud account, don't have anything more than plain text: no bold, no checklists. I'm guessing it's the difference between a plain text storage and rich text storage??

Comment: How did you "configure to use both iCloud accounts."? That's something I've been trying to do successfully for 20 years, since the original iTunes became me.com

Comment: Internet Account under System Settings, click the account (assuming you've already added and set a 2nd icloud account), then enable Notes.